# Is there a wastage of memory on extending the class in java where you require only a small bit of superclass in the subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

So I began to learn the inheritance concept in java a while ago and I came to a question that if we require on a small bit of superclass like a few bunch of members in the subclass, won't every variable get inherited in the subclass resulting in wastage of memory?

I tried various methods of solving it by changing the access specifiers but I want all the members to be used in a different inheritance only except this one. I couldn't think of any other way so please explain..

Comment: What makes you think there would be waste? Even if it _did_ copy over everything (which it doesn't), classes take up bytes of memory, _maybe_ kilobytes for "this should have been split up" huge classes. There is more than enough memory for them, extend away. But when you extend a class, that information is preserved in the compiled code. Only "the new bits" are stored in your extension and the runtime falls through to the original class for the bits you didn't overwrite.

Comment: Classes which extend a base class need to have all the behaviour and state of the base class, because they *are* an instance of the base class, as well as being an instance of the derived class. If you have a situation where you "require on[sic] a small bit of superclass" you need to think about your design.

Comment: A good design policy is:  use inheritance when you must, not whenever you can.  Don’t use inheritance just to make use of a class;  its methods are public for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It absolutely uses more memory but that is a small price to pay for the benefits in terms of maintainability, reusability and readability.

Essentially, trying to use less memory is considered an optimisation. Don’t optimise unless you know it’s [really necessary](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

The above was true decades ago when available memory was 1000s of times smaller.

If you have billions of instances of a class with a heavy base class then perhaps break it out by recoding (ie copy-and-paste from source) the specific fields and methods you need, otherwise follow the inheritance route.

A heavy base class has lots of fields (ie data), the storage for which gets duplicated in every instance of a inheriting class. Methods (aka functions) are not duplicated.